# How to restrict Quaternion.RotateTowards() to clockwise-only rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a speedometer script for rotaing the needle in the speedometer 
[image: The Speedometer]

```
public class Speedometer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float zeroRate = 3f;
    [SerializeField] PlayerController vehicle;
    void Update()
    {
        if (vehicle.IsOnGround())
        {
            float zRot = ((vehicle.speed * 2.237f) / vehicle.maxSpeed) * 180;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -zRot);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.identity, zeroRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm facing the problem that the needle sometimes does a full 360 to rotate towards `Quanternion.identity`. I could use an if condition to check if the value goes beyond 180, subtract the twice the difference but the condition would check for this in every `Update()` call and would just clutter code with a 1-time-use-only if-condition. Is there a function that restricts the rotate in clockwise/anti-clockwise direction?

Comment: so i dont see your solution code but i dont think you 'll have performance issue and the solution seems ok

Comment: The angles are mapped between 180 and -180 in Unity Editor, even if you input an angle above 180. I also think your solution is the way to go if that is working properly.

Comment: @KBaker well this sounds like exactly the issue .. if the value for any reason goes beyond 180 it is suddenly equal to -180 so `RotateTowards` seems to take the shortest way to rotate which is now the other way round

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could probably do something like store the last `zRot` value and over time reduce it and go

```
private float zRot;

void Update()
{
    if (vehicle.IsOnGround())
    {
        zRot = ((vehicle.speed * 2.237f) / vehicle.maxSpeed) * 180;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -zRot);
    }
    else
    {
        if(zRot > 0)
        {
            zRot -= zeroRate * Time.deltaTime; 
            // clamp to 0
            zRot = Mathf.Max(0, zRot);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -zRot);
        }
    }
}
```

Just that now `zeroRate` would be in `°/second` instead of `radians/second` in your version.